# This command only works... sometimes. What's wrong with it?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Here is the code:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_role('Moderator')
async def warn(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason):
    
    data = load_data()

    if str(member.id) in data:
        await ctx.send(f'{member.name} is in the JSON file.')
        data[str(member.id)].insert(0, reason)


    else:
        await ctx.send(f'{member.name} is not in the JSON file')
        data[str(member.id)] = [reason]
        
    dump_data(data)

    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    data[str(member.id)].remove(reason)

    dump_data(data)


def load_data():
    with open('warn_data.json') as f:
        return json.load(f)

def dump_data(data):
    with open('warn_data.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f)
```

Here's how the JSON file looks like (The `"Place": "Holder"` is only there because the command won't function if there is nothing inside the dictionary):

```json
{"Place": "Holder", "randomids": ["htis is a test"], "anotherrandomid": ["awjoid"]}
```

I want the bot to store the warn reason inside a JSON file and then delete it after a bit (it's currently 5 seconds for testing purposes) every time someone runs the command. Everything works fine except the deleting part.

If I run the command twice under 5 seconds, it will delete both values from the dictionary at the same time. If it gets spammed, it will delete some values from the lists, not all. It just keeps behaving unexpectedly and I don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: tl/dr, prob. race condition issue

Comment: Probably don't want to be spamming IO calls and opening that many files - it's slow, unnecessary, and leads to race issues like the one you have here. I would recommend you load it *once* at startup, and then autosave it when you close it / every x minutes.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Tl;Dr
when running asynchronously, if two things are meant to run at the same time, order is not guaranteed.

More explanation:

consider scenario where you are running this command twice.

First instance will have load_data() return empty and so will attempt to fill and write it to the file. it's data object is now `{'id':["item1"]}`

Second instance will have load_data() will have array with 1 item as stored by first instance. it'll add one more item to the array and store it. it's data object is `{'id': ["item1","item2"]}`

both instances are scheduled to run exactly after 5 seconds. almost at same time. this creates a race condition. it is not possible to define which will run first or second.

If first instance finished first, it'll remove item1 from it's data object and writes it. So file now looks like `{'id':[]}`. now second instance finishes and it'll modify it's data object and remove item 2 and write it to the file. which will look like `{'id':["item1"]}`

if second instance finished first, and first instance second, it'll produce result as u expected.

if you need to do this, the correct way is to load_data and modify it before writing. this should work all the time.

```py
lock = asyncio.Lock()

@bot.command()
@commands.has_role('Moderator')
async def warn(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason):
    await lock.acquire()
    data = load_data()
    if str(member.id) in data:
        data[str(member.id)].insert(0, reason)
    else:
        data[str(member.id)] = [reason]
    dump_data(data)
    lock.release()

    await ctx.send(f'{member.name} is not in the JSON file')

        
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    

    async with lock:
        data = load_data()  # this is the new line
        data[str(member.id)].remove(reason)
        dump_data(data)


def load_data():
    with open('warn_data.json') as f:
        return json.load(f)

def dump_data(data):
    with open('warn_data.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f)
```

### EDIT: added locks for multi threaded context

Comment: Your explanation is great but, unfortunately, your solution does not help and produces the same result as what it was in the original post.

Comment: is this running in multi threaded context? if that's the case, problem wont be resolved you will need mutexes in that case

Comment: No clear explanation of your issue.

Comment: do u mean answer, question or the comment? if it's question I dint write it. If it's answer i could not be more clear. if it's the comment I can update the answer with more explanation